# Bash Scripting -Use Of Regular Expression In Variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to bash scripting so please excuse me if i am asking the wrong question.

I am trying to write a script :)

```
First_Variable=800

Second_Variable=850
```

I want to feed all the number between First and Second variable to my script excluding 830. Say i am using seq command to count from first variable to second one but skip one number in between deliberately.

Any help??? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `seq`. Use brace expansion:

```
echo {800..829} {831..850}
```

If you really need the variables, you will need to use a for loop. You can build up an array using a loop easily enough:

```
arr=()
for ((i=First_Variable;i<Second_Variable;i++)); do
  (( i==830 )) || arr+=( $i )
done
```